# Prove that $ R $ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $ R $ be a relation on a set $ A $, and suppose that $ R $ is symmetric and transitive. Show that if for every $ x \in A $, there exists $ y \in A $ such that $ xRy $, then $ R $ is an equivalence relation.

**My attempt**

What you really have to prove is that $ R $ is reflexive, that is $ xRx $. So, let $ x \in A $, then there exists $ y \in A $ such that $ xRy $.

Since $ R $ is symmetric, we have $ yRx $.

In this way we have that for $ x \in A $, there exists $ y \in B $, such that $ xRy $ y $ yRx $, by transitivity we have $ xRx $, that shows that it is reflexive, therefore a relation of equivalence.

Comment: That's perfect!

Comment: Thanks :)). I appreciate.